# Create database backup using c# linq to sql (DataContext class)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Is there any function or method in linq to sql DataContext class for create data base backup in my specified path.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL is a query Language it is used to Query Data not for Maintaining your Data

Comment: but we can insert update and delete using Linq to Sql so why not make back up our database. This is a query available for backup our database "BACKUP DATABASE LA TO DISK='myDisk'".

Comment: @MayurDongre Query means to manipulate Data From Database weather it is accesing Data or Inseting Data From Database not to Maintain Backup Database so this Question does'nt belong to LINQ to SQL

Comment: So for that I have to craete stored procedure and call that procedure in Linq to Sql ?